# Vue.js SPA with Laravel API

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, single-page-application

I have a problem with defining routes for frontend portion of the application. It is Vue.js with Vue Router. Since it is SPA I think defining all routes in Laravel is not the correct answer but it seems I need to somehow because content is not served with current setup. Does Vue Router fetch the entire page and load it with each link? That would mean setting up a route for each link to load in Laravel routes. I think this is not intention of SPA decide.

So with route like

```
<route-link :to="{name: 'faq'}">FAQ</route-link>
```

Does this mean I must make a route

```
Route::get('faq', 'FaqController@index')->name('faq');
```

This is new architecture that is not well understand with me now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, SPA setup will fallback to "index.html" when no matched route

In **routes/web.php**:

```
Route::get('{path}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('path', '(.*)');
```

and vue-router will handle the rest

full setup: https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa/blob/master/routes/web.php